# Redirect calls from hidden numbers before I pick up

Tags: calls, automation, caller-id, hidden

I'm getting calls from a hidden number. Since the first call I've set up a blocking rule for hidden numbers, but they haven't stopped. I want to get a little more creative.

The next time they call, before I pick up, I want to redirect the call to the Dutch embassy in Dubai. I did some googling and Dubai numbers are the most expensive to call where I live.

Ideally, this will be automated, but I'm happy to do it myself the first few times. Is there a way to do this? I'd be happy to pay a few bucks for a third-party app.

Comment: [Call forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_forwarding)
is a carrier function. It's enabled by your carrier on request or by punching codes and may be a paid service. Contact them.

Comment: Deleted my answer , since it didn't address what you want and is only to reject for which many apps are also available on PS